# Calling Cython extension types from Numba jitted class

Tags: python, cython, numba

How would I go about calling a method of a Cython extension type from within a Numba jitted class? My minimal example below fails with the error I record below. How would I amend my minimal example to make it work?

Thanks for any help!!

### Minimal example

I have a Cython module, `shrubbery.pyx`:

```
cdef class Shrubbery:

    cdef int height

    def __init__(self, h):
        self.height = h

    def describe(self):
        print('This shrubbery is', self.height, 'tall.')
```

I have a setup file `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension('shrubbery', ['shrubbery.pyx'])]

setup(
    name='shrubbery',
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules)
```

I compile `shrubbery.pyx` into an extension type as usual (`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`). Then I try to use `Shrubbery` inside a numba jitted class as follows:

```
from shrubbery import Shrubbery
import numba as nb

spec = [('value', nb.int32)]


@nb.jitclass(spec)
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def size(self):
        return self.value

    def mixed_class_method(self):
        __shrubbery = Shrubbery(5)
        __shrubbery.describe()


# pure numba class: works
_b = Bag(value=3)
print(_b.size())

# pure cython extension type: works
__shrubbery = Shrubbery(5)
__shrubbery.describe()

# mix of cython extension type and numba jitted class: fails
_b.mixed_class_method()
```

### Error

```
/Users/mg/anaconda/bin/python3 test.py
3
('This shrubbery is', 5, 'tall.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    _b.mixed_class_method()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/jitclass/boxing.py", line 62, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 330, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 307, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 579, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 779, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 362, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 738, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 725, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 248, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 454, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 881, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 846, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 137, in propagate
    constraint(typeinfer)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 415, in __call__
    self.resolve(typeinfer, typevars, fnty)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 441, in resolve
    sig = typeinfer.resolve_call(fnty, pos_args, kw_args, literals=literals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1115, in resolve_call
    literals=literals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typing/context.py", line 204, in resolve_function_type
    return func.get_call_type_with_literals(self, args, kws, literals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/types/functions.py", line 199, in get_call_type_with_literals
    return self.get_call_type(context, args, kws)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/types/functions.py", line 193, in get_call_type
    return self.template(context).apply(args, kws)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typing/templates.py", line 207, in apply
    sig = generic(args, kws)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/jitclass/base.py", line 322, in generic
    sig = disp_type.get_call_type(self.context, args, kws)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/types/functions.py", line 250, in get_call_type
    template, pysig, args, kws = self.dispatcher.get_call_template(args, kws)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 269, in get_call_template
    self.compile(tuple(args))
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 579, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 779, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 362, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 738, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 725, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 248, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 454, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 880, in type_inference_stage
    infer.build_constraint()
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 802, in build_constraint
    self.constrain_statement(inst)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 961, in constrain_statement
    self.typeof_assign(inst)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1023, in typeof_assign
    self.typeof_global(inst, inst.target, value)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1119, in typeof_global
    typ = self.resolve_value_type(inst, gvar.value)
  File "/Users/mg/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1042, in resolve_value_type
    raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'Shrubbery': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>
File "test.py", line 16
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'mixed_class_method') for instance.jitclass.Bag#7fef29835df8<value:int32>)
[2] During: typing of call at <string> (3)
```

Comment: The documention for Numba implies that jitclass functions have to work in nopython mode. Since `Shrubbery` is a Python type as far as Numba is concerned I would not expect this to work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But there seem to be related attempts:
 http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/synapticarbors/rmath-cffi-example/blob/master/rmath-cffi-example.ipynb that do work. Any idea how to adapt the content of that link to my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a response to your suggestion in the comments that CFFI functions can be made to work. This is true, but it's **VERY** limitted.

You can convert a Cython `cdef` function to a CFFI function by going through a C function pointer. This conversion must take place in Cython. In order to work with Numba in `nopython` mode the `cdef` function must not take or return a Python object. This means that your `Shrubbery` class is not possible. A simple function that only accepts/returns C types will work

```
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t

cdef void f(int x) nogil:
    with gil:
        print(x+1)

ctypedef void (*void_int_func_pointer)(int)

def get_cffi_f():
    cdef void_int_func_pointer f_ptr = f
    cdef uintptr_t f_ptr_int = <uintptr_t>f_ptr

    from cffi import FFI
    ffi = FFI()
    return ffi.cast('void (*)(int)',f_ptr_int)
```

Within Python you call call `get_cffi_f()` to get a CFFI wrapping of `f` to pass to Numba functions. Note that I've declared the function as `nogil` and captured the GIL within it - I'm not 100% sure if Numba releases the GIL so I'm doing this to be safe. It may not be necessary.

You can then pass those CFFI wrappings into Numba or access them as global variables:

```
import numba as nb
from cy import get_cffi_f

func_global = get_cffi_f()

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def simple_func(func):
    func(5)
    func_global(6)
    func(7)

@nb.jitclass([('value', nb.int32)])
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    def mixed_class_method(self,func):
        func(self.value)
        func_global(self.value-1)

simple_func(get_cffi_f())
Bag(3).mixed_class_method(get_cffi_f())
```

My view is that trying to make something like a Cython class work here is a lost cause.

---

There's probably other ways of achieving the same thing - you could get Cython to make headers with `api` or `public` and use those headers with CFFI.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidW. As regards your last comment, *There's probably other ways of achieving the same thing - you could get Cython to make headers with `api` or `public` and use those headers with CFFI.*, which C struct did you have in mind? I.e. for which C struct could one get headers with `api` or `public` then use those headers with CFFI? Can we do that with Cython extension classes and bypass the problems above? Thank you.

Comment: No - this is only an alternative to writing `get_cffi_f`. It has all the same limitations. I don't really see a way of using the extension class here I'm afraid (there might be one, but I don't know what it is...)

Comment: One thing to clarify: you _can_ use Cython classes inside your `cdef` function (i.e. instead of the print that I put in the example), you just can't return them to Numba

Answer (score 0):

From the numba docs:

"All methods of a jitclass is compiled into nopython functions. The data of a jitclass instance is allocated on the heap as a C-compatible structure so that any compiled functions can have direct access to the underlying data, bypassing the interpreter."

As DavidW pointed out, Shrubbery is a Python type not a C type so you cannot use in a jitclass.

You could jit the individual methods though.